# Django : How to use select_related for a OneToOneField?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, one-to-one, django-select-related

I have created a OneToOneField(parent) in Child model with `related_name='children'`. In my views, I used `select_related` to get the queryset. But in my page the list of children associated to a parent shows empty.

Models.py:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.OneToOneField(Parent, unique = True, related_name = 'children')
    price = models.IntegerField()
```

views.py:

```
def live_prices(request):
    parent_queryset = Parent.objects.all().select_related('children')
    return render(request, 'live_prices.html', 'parent_queryset' : parent_queryset)
```

Template:

```
{% for parent in parent_queryset %}
{% child in parent.children.all %}
{{ child.price }}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @Bobort, Thanks, I have changed it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a one to one field, so you simply access `parent.children` (because you have `related_name='children'`) instead of looping through `parent.children.all()`.

Since there is only one child, I would remove the `related_name='children'`, then you will access `parent.child` instead of `parent.children`. You don't need `unique=True` for a one-to-one field either.

```
parent = models.OneToOneField(Parent)
```

Then, in your template:

```
{% for parent in parent_queryset %}
    {{ parent.child.price }}
{% endfor %}
```

Note that using `select_related` does not change the way you access the objects in the template, it just reduces the number of SQL queries.